# TKInter GUI formatting

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've been able to setup the program so that it works to my liking for the time being - still plenty of updates / changes to occur. One of my struggles on this right now is the GUI formatting.

I've specified the geometry of the main window, but I'm having issues with my label overflowing, spacing oddly, etc. whenever you click the back button. Each joke is a different length which is also causing overflow; jokes going off the screen, buttons getting pushed around, etc.

What's the best way to keep everything where it's supposed to go, regardless of how long each joke is? I have the jokes stored in a text file, I can upload that as well if needed.

```
import random as rand
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import WORD

#Create GUI using TKInter
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.jokes_told = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Bad Dad Jokes")
        self.root.geometry("600x400")
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 2)
        self.root.columnconfigure(2, weight = 2)
        self.root.columnconfigure(3, weight = 1)
        
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.add_btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Add New Joke", command = self.add_joke)
        self.joke_text = tk.Label(self.frame, text = joke + "\n" + punchline, height = 3, font = "18")
        self.next_btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Next", relief = "raised", command = self.joke_label)
        self.back_btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Back", relief = "raised", command = self.prev_joke)

        self.next_btn.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky="E", padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.add_btn.grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky="W", padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.joke_text.grid(column = 1, columnspan = 1, row = 2, sticky = "N", pady= 10, padx = 10)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()
    #Method to update joke text label on button click
    def joke_label(self):
        show_joke()
        self.jokes_told += 1
        self.show_backbtn()
        self.joke_text.config(text = joke + "\n" + punchline)
    
    #Creates GUI for new joke pop up
    def add_joke(self):
        self.add_box = tk.Toplevel()
        self.add_box.title("Add New Joke")
        self.add_box.geometry("400x300")
        self.new_joke_entry = tk.Entry(self.add_box)
        self.save_btn = tk.Button(self.add_box, text = "Save", relief="raised", command = self.save_joke)
        self.new_joke_entry.pack()
        self.save_btn.pack()

    #Saves new joke to jokes.txt
    def save_joke(self):
        new_joke = self.new_joke_entry.get()
        f = open("jokes.txt", "a")
        f.write(new_joke + "\n")
        f.close()
        self.add_box.destroy()

    #Displays the last joke told
    def prev_joke(self):
        get_last_joke()
        self.jokes_told -= 1
        self.show_backbtn()
        self.joke_text.config(text = joke + "\n" + punchline)
    
    #Show or hide the back button based on how many jokes have been read
    def show_backbtn(self):
        if self.jokes_told == 0:
            self.back_btn.grid_forget()
        elif self.jokes_told > 0:
            self.back_btn.grid(column=1, row = 3, sticky="E", padx=10, pady=10)

        

#Stores jokes loaded from text file
jokes = []
#Stores jokes that've been used to prevent repeats
used_jokes = []
joke = ""
punchline = ""

#Reads text file and appends each joke to the joke list
def get_jokes():
    f = open("jokes.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        jokes.append(line)

#Returns a random joke and splits it into joke and punchline when available
def get_random_joke():
    global joke, punchline
    rand_joke = rand.randint(0, len(jokes) - 1)
    cur_joke = jokes[rand_joke]
    #Check if jokes list is empty
    if len(jokes) > 0:
        if "..." in cur_joke:
            joke = cur_joke.split("...")[0]
            punchline = cur_joke.split("...")[1]
        else:
            joke = cur_joke
    #If jokes list is empty, we recycle old jokes
    else:
        for joke in used_jokes:
            used_jokes.remove(joke)
            jokes.append(joke)

    used_jokes.append(cur_joke)
    jokes.remove(cur_joke)

#Function to test generated jokes
def show_joke():
    global joke, punchline
    joke = ""
    punchline = ""
    get_random_joke()
    print(joke + "\n" + punchline)

#Gets last used joke
def get_last_joke():
    global joke
    last_joke = len(used_jokes) - 2
    joke = used_jokes[last_joke]

#Start with this function to read text file and generate joke list
get_jokes()

MyGUI()
```

Comment: You should provide only the code needed to reproduce the problem.
WE do not need all of your code just the hand full of lines responsible for formatting and presenting the data.

Comment: We can't help w/out jokes.txt

Comment: What's the recommended way for me to upload the txt file?

Comment: Have you looked into [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)?